# Java: Need to find common availability for all emails in Microsoft Graph getSchedule API

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use graph /getSchedule api to check for meeting conflict.

My basic requirement is to pass a start and end dateTime and see if the resource is available(free/busy). Although I am able to get that in /getSchedule Api but not sure on some of the fields in request and response.

Request:

```
ICalendarGetScheduleCollectionPage response = graphClient.users("usrEmailAddress").calendars(calendar.id)
.getSchedule(schedulesList,endTime,startTime,availabilityViewInterval)
.buildRequest()
.post();
```

Below is my sample response(both time the availabilityViewInterval value is 5 in request but response availabilityView is different):

```
"availabilityView": "22",
"scheduleItems": [
    {
        "isPrivate": false,
        "status": "busy",
        "subject": "Test Meeting again",
        "location": "",
        "start": {
            "dateTime": "2020-06-12T10:58:45.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "end": {
            "dateTime": "2020-06-12T11:08:45.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
    }
],
"workingHours": {
    "daysOfWeek": [
        "monday",
        "tuesday",
        "wednesday",
        "thursday",
        "friday"
    ],
    "startTime": "08:00:00.0000000",
    "endTime": "17:00:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": {
        "name": "India Standard Time"
    }
```

Response 2:

```
"availabilityView": "00",
"scheduleItems": \[\],
"workingHours": {
"daysOfWeek": \[
"monday",
"tuesday",
"wednesday",
"thursday",
"friday"
\],
"startTime": "08:00:00.0000000",
"endTime": "17:00:00.0000000",
"timeZone": {
"name": "India Standard Time"
}
```

Response 3:

```
"availabilityView": "220000000000",
"scheduleItems": \[
{
"isPrivate": false,
"status": "busy",
"subject": "Test Meeting again",
"location": "",
"start": {
"dateTime": "2020-06-12T10:58:45.0000000",
"timeZone": "UTC"
},
"end": {
"dateTime": "2020-06-12T11:08:45.0000000",
"timeZone": "UTC"
}
}
\],
"workingHours": {
"daysOfWeek": \[
"monday",
"tuesday",
"wednesday",
"thursday",
"friday"
\],
"startTime": "08:00:00.0000000",
"endTime": "17:00:00.0000000",
"timeZone": {
"name": "India Standard Time"
}
```

Note: The start and end time for all the request were different but availabilityViewInterval field was 5 in all the cases.

I am referring below Microsoft document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java

Use Case: To find availability common to all email ids in response. I am planning to use availabilityView as base to calculate and find common data.
If anyone have a better design please help me. Thank you.

Use Case: To find availability common to all email ids in response. I am planning to use availabilityView as base to calculate and find common data.